# PyAutoGui module not working in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to use PyAutoGui's `locateCenterOnScreen()` function in PyCharm. However, it always throws an error even though it works in VS Code. I am running on an M1 Macbook Air w/ macOS Monterey. I have PyAutoGui version 0.9.53 installed. Does anyone know why it does this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Files/Programming/Projects/Auto Mining Tool/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('image.png')
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 207, in locateCenterOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andrewwalker/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 413, in locateCenterOnScreen
    coords = locateOnScreen(image, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andrewwalker/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 372, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
  File "/Users/andrewwalker/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 477, in _screenshot_osx
    im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

Comment: There's an error in the logic in the `pyscreeze` module. From the command line, run `pip install pillow` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you why, but I'm not smart enough to know how to fix it.
The reason seems to stem from updates. I just ran into this problem today myself, I typically build projects and then never update modules etc.

Did you update modules prior to this happening?

It seems they've changed function names, and other modules that were built by other people either were not updated, or have import errors, resulting in pyscreeze and pyautogui not playing nice together.